# Can I reset Real time database storage in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I am using Firebase spark FREE plan and want to know what if I want to reset my data again to 0 Byte and clear all storage from Real Time database? [image: Storage used screenshot] for example if I want to reset all data and make it 0 again as it was when I made project, what steps to follow and is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete all data the database in either the Firebase console, or through its API by calling `remove` on the root.

If you've done that and there still are some bytes showing in the console screenshots, those might be some leftover metadata for the database. If that is the case, there's nothing you can do about it, and you only have 1GM - 515 bytes that you can still add to it on the free plan.

Comment: And also even no user is active still console is showing 5 active users. Edit:  I can say this because this app is not launched on only my one friend has this app

Comment: That seems like a different problem.